# How to be able to click on input that is inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I am using the following code:

```
 <div class="filled dropdown">
            <form>
                <div class="multiple-wrapper dropdown">
                    <input type='checkbox' id='goption14' name="Questions" onclick='addQuestion();' value='14'><label for="goption14" class="checkbox">Able to handle short-term expenses?</label>
                    <div class="question-boxes inner-wrapper">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"><label for="checkbox1">Acid Ratio</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"><label for="checkbox2">Cash Ratio</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"><label for="checkbox3">Current Ratio</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4"><label for="checkbox4">Net Working Capital</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like when I click the *Able to handle short-term expenses* label:

[image]

Now what I'm trying to do is call the `addQuestion` function when I click on this label.

However, since I have everything wrapped in: `<div class="multiple-wrapper dropdown">`
it doesn't seem to be able to reach the: `<input type='checkbox' id='goption14' name="Questions" onclick='addQuestion();' ...`

And therefore it is not calling the `addQuestion` function which aims to increase the `Questions` counter and apply a border to the left of the *Able to handle short-term expenses* label.

Is there a way for me to still be able to get this dropdown menu and wrapper when clicking the *Able to handle short-term expenses* label, but also checking the checkbox: `<input type='checkbox' id='goption14' name="Questions" onclick='addQuestion();' ...`
and so calling its `onclick` method `addQuestion`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing the whole code, I suspect you are writing the `addQuestion()` function in a place that is not accessible in the global scope.

Meaning if you are using jQuery, your `addQuestion()` may be wrapped inside of a `$(document).ready()`, making the `addQuestion()` invisible to the global scope, where your `<input onclick="addQuestion()">` is located.

**Solution 1 (recommended)**

Include `document.getElementById('goption14').addEventListener('click', addQuestion)` or `jQuery('#goption14').on('click', addQuestion)` within same scope of where your `addQuestion()` function is written.

**Solution 2 (not recommended)**

Include the following in your HTML

```
<script>
    function addQuestion(){
        /*
            your function
        */
    }
</script>
```

**Solution 3 (least recommended)**

Write the onclick event like this:

```
<input ... onclick="function addQuestion(){ ... }; addQuestion();" ... >
```

Comment: My `addQuestion()` function is written as your Solution 2 at the moment, and it's placed at the end of the file. When I get rid of the `dropdown` class from `<div class="multiple-wrapper dropdown">` I am able to call the function and things work as expected. When I add it back then I get issues.

Comment: @SamPetrus did you try solution 1?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Added a click event for the outside div which finds the next `input` id and simulates as if I had clicked it myself.

```
  $('.multiple-wrapper.dropdown').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('input').attr('id');
            $('#'+id).click();
        });
```

Then it is calling the `addQuestion()` function properly, etc.

Comment: well, isn't this what I said in my proposed solution 1?

Comment: It is similar, however the issue was that an onclick was never recognized as clicking the input when I clicked the label. Whenever I clicked the label the onclick was recognized as clicking the `.multiple-wrapper.dropdown` so I had to work from there.